# how to force https before www in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, hsts

I am trying to finalize HSTS compliance and am a Web guy but this is over my head.

My current .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" env=HTTPS
```

I am using: https://hstspreload.org/ to check compliance and when I run this tool for my domain it returns:

`http://example.com` (HTTP) should immediately redirect to `https://example.com` (HTTPS) before adding the www subdomain. Right now, the first redirect is to `https://www.example.com/`. The extra redirect is required to ensure that any browser which supports HSTS will record the HSTS entry for the top level domain, not just the subdomain.

How do I force https first?

Multiple redirects is ok, but I want to make sure https is first.

Comment: So multiple redirects is fine with you? 1. `http -> https` and 2. add `www`

Comment: Thanks for the question, I updated the OP to reflect.  I am ok with a 2nd redirect, especially becuase it will only come up when user uses none https and no www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have your redirects like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http -> https keeping same domain
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]

# then add www while keeping it https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```